# Transform scaled numbers to raw numbers in R

Tags: r, scale

I'm new in R. I would like to transform a set of numbers I have scaled using `scale()` to the original raw ones.

Here the code I used to scale the numbers

```
dataCluster <- dataFinal[, c(1)]
data_z <- as.data.frame(lapply(dataCluster, scale))
clusters <- kmeans (na.roughfix(data_z), 3)
```

where:

- `dataFinal` is a data frame (3 columns x 100 rows)
- `clusters` is a "data matrix" (3 columns x 3 rows).

I would like to create a `clustersRaw` with the raw values.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @RichardScriven First blood :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know it this is going to solve, since you dind't provide your data. However:

```
    #create a matrix 10x3
    mat<-matrix(1:30,ncol=3)
    #scale it
    x<-scale(mat)
    #restore it
    t(t(x)*attr(x,"scaled:scale")+attr(x,"scaled:center"))
```